# Find the basis of $W$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and use the answer to find a basis for $W^⊥$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

**Question:** Find a basis for the subspace $W$ of $\mathbb R^3$, then use it to find a basis for $W^⊥$.
$$W = \{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}, 2x-y+3z=0 \}$$

I'm kinda confused about what the $W$ set above contains. Is it simply referring to the two vectors ($[1, 1, 1]$ and $[2, -1, 3]$) that span the subspace of $W$? In that case, how would we compute the basis for $W^⊥$?

I'd much appreciate if someone could show me how this is done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think $W$ is the set of all $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ such that $2x-y+3x=0$, which is a plane; it has a normal vector

Comment: Ah I see! So would $[2, -1, 3]$ be the only vector that spans $R^3$ in this case then?

Comment: $(2,-1,3)$ spans $W^\perp$.  You would need three vectors to span $\mathbb R^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think intended was what would usually be written with a $\mid$ or colon instead of a comma:

$W$ is the set of all $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ such that $2x-y+3z=0$.  $W$ is a plane.

We can eyeball that $W$ is spanned by $(1,2,0)$ and $(0,3,1)$.

The orthogonal space is spanned by $(1,2,0)\times(0,3,1)=(2,-1,3)$, a vector perpendicular to the plane and the vectors we gave spanning it.  This normal vector can also be obtained from the equation for the plane, which is $(2,-1,3)\cdot(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: $2x-y+3z=0\implies z=-\frac23x+\frac y3$, so the vectors that span this plane are $(x,y,-\frac23 x+\frac y3)$

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is a plane through the origin.  You just need two linearly independent solutions.  Say $(2,1,-1)$  and $(0,3,1)$.

You could take their cross product to get the normal.  Or, if you know anything about equations of planes, you can read off $(2,-1,3)$ as the normal direction.  And it's a basis for $W^{\perp}$.